# Is it possible to pipe the password to login as root , rather that typing the password when it prompts in command line?? - Korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, root, su

I have a custom requirement by a specific user , that he wants me to write a shell script to move files from one folder to another folder . These two folders have different owners

Now, I managed to do that by logging in as root, but want to achieve this without giving root privileges to user.

I am not allowed to do any new package installation,
Not allowed to use any another shell than Korn .

Please suggest a solution.
Yeah I know this is not a safer way and a bad approach, still am curious about satisfying the need of a user ..

Comment: Use sudo and/or setup permissions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a script to move files.
2. change the ownership of the script to root
3. Update the /etc/sudoers file to give the user permissions to run the script as root:

   `user ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/script.sh`
4. User can execute the script: 
    `sudo /opt/script.sh`
   That shouldn't ask for root password, but give the user privileges to run the script as root.

Comment: thanks for your reply . let me ask you a doubt about your reply. So. The script.sh now turn out into a file that can be able to execute by anyone in the system, who have acces to run the file with root access. What if I want to restrict this file can be accessible to only one user . Is it possible ???

Comment: Change `user ALL` in @Ram's answer to `user userid`